# Permission Denial in Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, permissions, receiver

I am trying to make broadcast receiver from app B to A but can't seem to communicate due to the error message (see below). Besides, I was trying to search this forum for answer to tackle the specified problem but none of them seems helpful to me due to difference in situations.

Error:

```
2019-03-28 07:24:23.973 1636-1650/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA flg=0x30 } to com.example.cataloguemoviefinal/receiver.UpdateWidgetDataReceiver requires com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA due to sender com.example.favoritefilmapp (uid 10147)
```

Manifest:

Permission in App A:

```
<!-- Permission declaration for updating widget content -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA" />
```

Receiver in App A:

```
<!-- Custom Broadcast receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.UpdateWidgetDataReceiver"
            android:permission="com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Broadcast receiver in App A:

```
public class UpdateWidgetDataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        Log.d("Action intent", intent.getAction());

        if(intent.getAction() != null){
            if(intent.getAction().equals("com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA")){
                // Log message
                Log.d("Testing receiver", "I got ur updates");

                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

                int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, FavoriteMovieItemWidget.class));

                appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.favorite_movie_stack_view);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Manifest in App B:

```
 <!-- This code is used for custom BroadcastReceiver -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA"/>
```

Sender message in App B:

```
// Intent for broadcast receiver
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        // Add flags to intent which can be communicated with closed app package (idk if its true)
        broadcastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        // Set action
        broadcastIntent.setAction("com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA");
        // Sent broadcast to receiver (use permission)
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent, "com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA");
```

What should I do in order for broadcast receiver to receive the message from app B to A (show Log.message)?

Sorry if I wrote a little bit too much code, but those are the neccesary part for possible error.

Thanks.

Comment: Trying to use:
`<!-- Permission declaration for updating widget content -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA" />`
 and
`<uses-permission android:name="com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.receiver.UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA"/>`

but cannot seem to deliver message either

Comment: Error : 
`2019-03-28 08:17:04.887 1636-1650/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=com.example.cataloguemoviefinal.receiver.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET_DATA flg=0x30 } to com.example.cataloguemoviefinal/.receiver.UpdateWidgetDataReceiver`

Answer (score 0):

Android O has a implicit broadcast limit , are you running on Android o or above ?
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background ,search "Broadcast Limitations"

Comment: Yea, I forgot to update about it, I handled it by using permission protection level signature due to signature has exception regarding to broadcast limit